# How to access USB device in HID mode in C#

Tags: c#, usb, hid

I want to access data received from Micro-controller configured as a USB HID Device. How to detect and access the device for byte by byte data transfer?

Comment: HID devices generally pretend to be either a keyboard or mouse. Have the common approaches to hooking these been unhelpful? Please elaborate on what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the basic Windows Hid APIs:
https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Device.Net/blob/master/src/Hid.Net/Windows/HidAPICalls.cs

Here is an example of how to access a device on Windows 10:
https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Device.Net/blob/master/src/Hid.Net.UWP/UWPHidDevice.cs

This is the documentation for Windows 10 Hid access:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.humaninterfacedevice

Here is an Android example:
https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Hid.Net/blob/master/Hid.Net.Android/AndroidHidDevice.cs

Here is the documentation for C# Android:
https://developer.xamarin.com/api/namespace/Android.Hardware.Usb/

Whichever solution you use for the platform you are working on, you should come up with a common interface to sit across all the platforms. Here is an example:
https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Device.Net/wiki/IDevice